# My Theme - whishlist Page Design Not Working

Tags: theme

i have installed the whole package but now i have 1 little problem. the pages: my account, whishlist, cart, checkout and login does not have the same themelayout. the still have the standard magento layout. can you please tell me how to change ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that system->configuration->design->package

has the package name option set as your current package name.

After that clear magento's cache by going to system->cache management->flush magento cache and click all the cache options and select refresh.

That should solve your problem.